# LSP - Liskov Substitution Principle particular case

Tags: liskov-substitution-principle

i'am not sure about special case of LSP.
Actually child should extend implementation of parent and not change it.
For me means extension, that i add new lines in child implementation to parent
implementation within child class.
But what about, when i completely override parent-implementation and it provides
result too?

Parent is:

```
public class Calculator {
     public void computeProfit(){
        int profit = 2+2;
     }
}
```

Child is:

```
public class SpecialCalculator  extends Calculator {
    @Override
    public void computeProfit(){
        //overriding completely parent-implementation
        int profit = Math.pow(2) * 5;
    }
}
```

has LSP still been preserved?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; In you example LSP is preserved.
IMO the thing with SOLID principles it that it is a mnemonic for [dynamic polymorphism](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-method-dispatch-runtime-polymorphism-java/) so the end goal for your code is to enable something like this

```
public void SomeBusinessLogic(Calculator calc) {
  calc.computeProfit() // SpecialCalculator might go here as well
}
```

Your code is perfectly fit for this.

This however would violate LSP

```
public class SpecialCalculator  extends Calculator {
    public void computeProfitClevrly(){
        //overriding completely parent-implementation
        int profit = Math.pow(2) * 5;
    }
}
```

because now you'll have to do something like

```
public void SomeBusinessLogic(Calculator calc) {
  if (calc is SpecialCalculator)
     calc.computeProfitCleverly() // SpecialCalculator might go here as well
}
```

P.S. There are some more subtle cases of LSP violation. I.e. when base class is `ImmutablePoint` and a child class is a point that might be mutated.

Comment: thx, computeProfitClevrly() is not defined in Calculator class?

Comment: yw, yes it's defined only in `SpecialCalculator`